# Send duplicate rows from gridview to another gridview in another page

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, webforms

So I have a gridview with sqldatasource. 
I have a column called duplicate where if firstname or lastname or email already exists the value of duplicate will be yes. 
[image]

What i want to do is when the user press the "Yes" on a row I want To redirect the user to a new page with a gridview with the duplicate rows of that row the user pressed yes on. 
So only show the duplicates with that row, 
I added a new gridview on another page and im passing the id of the row user pressed yes on and i tried something like this

```
SELECT * FROM [applied] WHERE ([isDuplicate] = @isDuplicate AND [firstName]=@firstName AND [lastName]=@lastName OR [Email]=@Email)
```

But the new gridview is empty
any idea how can I do such a thing?

Comment: have you tried using send the data using session variables.

Comment: use this `select * from mytable where isDuplicate = 'yes'` on other page and bind with gridview.

Comment: @PRATEEKGHOSH no I haven't
Is it a better way?

Comment: @Asif.Ali select * from mytable where isDuplicate = 'yes' returns only the row the user selected but not all its duplicates

Comment: Yes this will definitely work there may be some more better ways of doing but this will surely work for you just give it a try

Comment: @PRATEEKGHOSH do you have an idea on how i can pass the row data as a session ?

Comment: Yes try to find the your cells values containing your first name and last name also the email id on yes link click and store them in seperate session variable repectively.

Comment: @PRATEEKGHOSH Row in session variables??? And if there are 6000 repeated rows? It's not the right way! you can just store row ids and then use them again to retrieve data from database.

Comment: @Emanuele i said it on yes button click if there are 6000 duplicate rows then also only one at time data i am asking to take out the time he click of yes button respected user name and email whatever he want he can take it from that row only and take this session variable to next page for next grid view